# Javascript date string conversion

Tags: javascript, date, casting

I have a system that returns a JSON object that contains dates in string format.

These dates are in the format "2012-10-19 06:05:38 GMT" (no... I'm stuck with them like this)

So I need to get this into a date object (d) ready to output as d.toLocaleDateString()

In chrome it works perfectly by just passing the string to a new Date (Bad bad Chrome - makes Eric lazy), but of course it fails in FF and IE

I can fix it by splitting the string but its not pretty and I've not figured out dealing with the offsets from GMT.

There must be a more elegant way...?

I'm sure someone here can do it in one line.

Comment: If you don't have to deal with different timezone, offset seems unnecessary; if you have to, and if it always comes as GMT (UTC), `Date` object has a bunch of `setUTCXXX` method, and a static `UTC` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite a one-liner, but if you know all your dates will be GMT, something like the following should work:

```
function parseDate(dateString) {
    // [y, m, d, hr, min, sec]
    var parts = dateString.match(/\d+/g);

    // Months are 0-indexed
    parts[1] -= 1;

    return new Date(Date.UTC.apply(Date, parts));
}
```

Comment: Oh that is neat +1 now and probably the big tick when I get back into the office tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, and had access to the serverside script gathering that information (and outputting it) I would convert the date into a unix timestamp, and then make Javascript process that using the Date constructor easily.

**EDIT:** You can use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert the string date into numeric unix timestamp if you're using PHP.

Comment: I wish I had, but no, the server-side stuff comes from the REST API of a COTS application

Answer (score 2):

If you know the exact format, you could use a library such as Moment.js: [Documentation for Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/).

To parse:

```
var dateString = "2012-10-19 06:05:38 GMT".replace(" GMT", "");
var date = moment(dateString, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: My preference would be date.js - that would eat this problem. But I'd prefer to do it without falling back on a library

Comment: @EricT: I'm also a fan of date.js, but unfortunately it's no longer actively developed and I've encountered several bugs with it, but you may well be able to use it here. If I have a chance I will take a shot at a library-free solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can  just parse the dateString manually，and pass the Date the Date constructor exactly：https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

```
   var dateString = "2012-10-19 06:05:38 GMT".split(" "),
       date = dateString[0].split("-"),
       time = dateString[1].split(":");

   var dateObj = new Date(date[0],date[1]-1,date[2],time[0],time[1],time[2]);
```